# How to pre-fill a form using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, popup, autofill

I have to pre-fill a form on this page that I open using javascript. The best code I have managed to come up with thus far is

```
submitpage = window.open('http://localhost/bookmarks/submitbookmark');
submitpage.getElementsByName("title")[0].value="Good Luck";
```

I have no control over the page that opens. When I manually fill the form, it works fine and submits everything. Its when I pass variables in the url that it does not accept some. The problem is that none of the form elements on the third party page have id's, so i have to use the `getElementsByName()` function but the good thing is that there are only four elements, all with unique names so i can use the function like this `getElementsByName()[0]`.

Now, I want to see the form pre-filled with values and leave the option of submitting to the user by clicking the submit/post button. Just for reference, the form `method="POST"`.

Comment: Please do post if you think passing variables and writing a submit by $_post script is a better idea. It has been suggested to me as an alternative. If that is a better option indeed, then please identify a possible resource for me as well. I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: If the form is not on the same domain it will not work.
What is the issue now? Errors in the console? and by $_post script - do you mean on the server using PHP or on the client using jQuery ajax?

Comment: precisely... that is what i meant... I feared that might be the case... the website is not on the same domain... so i should use requests as in jquery and ajax... thanks!!

i would request the admin to close this post... thanks!!

Comment: You can delete it yourself? Also you cannot post using jquery to another site either as far as I know. Serverside php using CURL for example

Comment: I dont quite understand the question "You can delete it yourself?"

Anyway, I can write a post method for a page... I think that is possible using http requests... I'm not sure how but I think it can be done...

Comment: People who ask questions here can normally delete their own questions - in your case perhaps you have too little rep to do so. Hence the question

Comment: Thanks! I stated the problem and now, I've been granted access to the server... I wanted to do it on the client side but I dont have an option... I'll post my resolution once I get it running... Thanks for the help though... I appreciate it!